# Discord.js command that gives a role

Tags: javascript, command, bots, discord, discord.js

so I'm trying to make a command that where you type `$test` and it gives you, for example, a "Test" role. This is my current code but I keep getting an error: "Cannot read property 'addRole' of undefined"

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { send } = require("process");
const { clear } = require("console");
const client = new Discord.Client();
var prefix = "$";

client.login("token");

//TEST COMMAND
client.on("message", message => {

    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "test")) {
        message.channel.send("You have been given `Need to be tested` role! You will be tested shortly!")
        client.channels.get("701547440310059059").send(` please test ${message.author}!`)
        const member = message.mentions.members.first();
        let testRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.id == "609021049375293460")
        member.addRole(testRole)
        
    }})
    
    
client.on('ready',()=>{
    console.log(`[READY] Logged in as ${client.user.tag}! ID: ${client.user.id}`);
    let statuses = [
        "  status "
    ]
    setInterval(function(){
            let status = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)];
            client.user.setActivity(status, {type:"WATCHING"})
    
        }, 3000) //Seconds to Random
});
```

Please let me know how I can do this easily or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In discord.js **v12**, GuildMember does not have a function `.addRole`, you need to use [GuildMemberRoleManager's](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) `.add`, also you need to add `.cache` when getting roles from server, like this:

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
        let testRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == "609021049375293460")
        member.roles.add(testRole)
```

Comment: Hey, so this is my updated code but I get an error: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined. 

``client.on("message", message => {

    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "test")) {
        message.channel.send("You have been given `Need to be tested` role! You will be tested shortly!")
        client.channels.get("701547440310059059").send(` please test ${message.author}!`)
        const member = message.mentions.members.first();
        let testRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == "609021049375293460")
        member.roles.add(testRole)
        
    }})``

Comment: Hey, make sure you're running discord.js v12 by checking your package.json file. If you're not, you should maybe try switching to it, because v11 will be discontinued by the end of the year. If you need help switching to v12, you can check [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)

Comment: I managed to update it now, now I'm getting a "cannot read property 'roles' of undefined"
``client.on("message", message => {

    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "test")) {
        message.channel.send("You have been given `Need to be tested` role! You will be tested shortly!")
        client.channels.cache.get("701547440310059059").send(` please test ${message.author}!`)
        const member = message.mentions.members.first();
        let testRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == "609021049375293460")
        member.roles.add(testRole)
        
    }})``

Comment: Are you sending this command in a server? Because it works for me

Comment: weird, yeah I'm in a test server, command is `$test`

Comment: I found out `$test` crashes but `$test @user` kinda works but doesn't give the role. I'll check if I got the role ID correct

Comment: "DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions" I do not know why this happens..

Comment: You should maybe implement a check if the command contains a mention by adding `if(!message.mentions.members.first()) return;` before, for example, the message.channel.send, because it may crash if someone sends the command and there is no mention.

Comment: `"DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions" I do not know why this happens..` this probably means that the bot does not have permission to manage roles

Comment: I have just added the `if(!message.mentions.members.first()) return message.channel.send("mention someone")` works fine but the bot should have administrator so it should work, correct?

Comment: this is the full error after $test @user
`(node:512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (c:\Users\user\Desktop\Modraj discord bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
warning.js:27
(node:512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)`

Comment: This error can also happen when the role you are trying to assign is higher than the bot's role

Comment: Hey, just another question, how could I make it so whoever uses `$test` they get the role, so without mentioning anyone?

Comment: To get the message author member, just use `message.member.roles.add` instead of `member.roles.add` [1](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member), and so you can also remove the check for the mention

Comment: Hey, sorry for late reply, so the code should look like this? I get an error: "cannot read property 'roles' of undefined"
``client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "test2")) {
        const member = message.mentions.members.first();
        if(member.roles.cache.has("609021049375293460")) return message.channel.send("You already have the role!")
        message.channel.send("you've been given the role")
        let testRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == "609021049375293460")
        message.member.roles.add(testRole)
 }})``

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you are getting the error `Cannot read property 'addRole' of undefined`.

This means that the member variable is undefined, which could be caused by the fact that you didn't mention a member.

In this line, you put `const member = message.mentions.members.first();` which means when you run the command, you have to mention someone to add the role to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks but I already solved the problem if you check the previous answer, but thank you :D

Comment: :D have a great day

Answer (score 0):

In newest version of discord.js you can try the following code:

```
       // Where '799617378904178698' is your role id
       message.guild.roles.fetch('799617378904178698')
            .then(role => {
                    console.log(`The role color is: ${role.color}`);
                    console.log(`The role name is: ${role.name}`);
                    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
                    member.roles.add(role).catch(console.error);
                })
            .catch(console.error);
```

Works in case you're trying to add a *certain* role. You ought to call it like that:

```
(prefix)commandName @member
```

Answer (score 0):

Found one more solution in case you want to give any role to any user (except bot)

main.js (or index.js whatever you have):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client(); 
const prefix = '+';
const fs = require("fs");

client.commands = new Discord.Collection()
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online');
}); 

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    console.log(args);

    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command == 'giveany') {
        const role = args[1].slice(3, args[1].length - 1);
        client.commands.get('giveany').execute(message, args, role);
    }
});

client.login('token');
```

giveany.js :

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'giveany',
    description: 'adds any role to a member',
    execute(message, args, role) {
        console.log(role);
        message.guild.roles.fetch(role)
            .then(r => {
                console.log(`The role color is: ${r.color}`);
                console.log(`The role name is: ${r.name}`);
                let member = message.mentions.members.first();
                if (member != undefined) {
                    console.log('member=' + member);
                    member.roles.add(r).catch(console.error);
                } else {
                    message.channel.send('You cannot give a role to a user that is either bot or undefined');
                }
            }).catch( (error) => {
                console.error(error);
                message.channel.send('Could not find given role: ' + args[1]);
            });
    }
}
```

Calling: `+giveany @Username @Role`